# Command line to shell script not working

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I am trying to convert one command in single line into a script so that it can be called from a scheduler.
But the command is working when I run in bash, bot doesn't run properly when I run it in shell script.

I have the below data in a file $FILE1

```
1,Date,Country,Europe,6
2,Date,Country,America,22
3,Date,Country,America,22
4,Date,Country,Asia,9
5,Date,Country,Australia,29
```

and my expected output is to only put country names and number more than 20 count and only unique values
for eg:

```
America, 22 MILLION
Australia, 29 MILLION
```

This is my code which is not giving me unique values, instead its giving all duplicate values

```
#This will only pull Country column i.e. America, Australia and so on...
grep "Country" FILE1|cut -f4 "," > $FILE2


#This will use the keyword America from FILE2 and search in FILE1 for associated count and copy in FILE3
for i in $(cat $FILE2);
do
     cat $FILE1|grep "Country"|grep $i|echo $i, `wc -l` MILLION >> $FILE3;
done;


#Now that we have both country name and count...we will find countries only with >20 count
for a in $(cat $FILE3);
do
    awk -F "," '$2 > 20' $FILE3 |sort -u > $FILE4
done;


#Send the final file to email
echo "Here is the data"|mailx -s "Population data" -a FILE4 user@email
```

My 2nd question is, how do I format in a good way...for eg I want to write"

```
America has more than 22 million population
Australia has more than 29 million population
```

instead of

```
America, 22 million
Australia, 29 million
```

Thanks. Sorry if its a basic question...I am just starting out in Unix scripting.

Comment: If you speak about duplicate entries, is the entire line (except the first field) identical, or only certain fields (like country name and/or population), but the others could be different?

Comment: unless you just hide it, you do not define, in your code, FILE1, FILE2, FILE3 and FILE4, so each time the shell may replace `$FILEn` with an empty string... as $unknownvar is replaced with an empty string. And most of the time you better surround the $var with doublequotes:  `"$var"`

Comment: And I do not understand why you loop : `for a in $(cat $FILE3);` but do nothing with $a, and each time call : `awk -F "," '$2 > 20' $FILE3 |sort -u > $FILE4` (which doesn't use $a, and could just be called only once and would give the same result ?)

Answer (score 2):

You could combine the entire text-processing task into one `awk` program:

```
awk -F',' '($5>20)&&(!seen[$4]++){printf "%s has more than %d million inhabitants\n",$4,$5}' data.csv
```

This will parse the file as CSV file, inspect the 5th field to check whether it is larger than 20, and keep an internal occurence counter `seen` to ensure that the country name has not yet been encountered. Only if both conditions are met, it will print the desired string, assembled from the information in fields 4 and 5.

To include it in a shell script:

```
awk -F',' '($5>20)&&(!seen[$4]++){printf "%s has more than %d million inhabitants\n",$4,$5}' "$file1" > "$file4"
```

As a side note, it is good practice to *not* use all-uppercase names for shell variables unless you want to export them as environment variables, and to ensure proper quoting of shell variables to prevent unwanted word splitting.

I would recommend looking into [GreyCat&Lhunath's Bash Guide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) for more information on shell scripting. Also, consider installing [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net), which will help catch many syntax errors in shell scripts.